# Prestashop how to replace left column with a gallery only on one page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to put a gallery instead off left column but only on one page, but i don't find the pagename on theme => advanced.

Comment: In what page do you need it?

Answer (score 1):

Go in `Module -> Position`, search your module and find the hook `displayLeftColumn`.
Then click on `Edit`, under the `Exceptions` box select all the page where you want to 'hide' that module.
You're done